# Table's ID disappears after select tag inserted into form

Tags: jquery, http-post, jquery-events

I have a web page which posts to a server and the server returns some HTML:

```
<select id="selectmodel"><option value="0">Model</option></select>
```

This HTML goes into a TD tag (#td2) as shown below and all seemingly works fine:

```
$.post("/cgi-bin/gcp.dll/modelx",{ manufacturerVal: window.manufacturerVal}, function(data) {$('#td2').html(data)});
```

However, it seems that some other ID's disappear. When I try the line below before the post, it works fine. Afterwards, it no longer works:

```
$("#td5").click(function() {if (document.getElementById("table2")){alert("table2 exists")}else{alert("table2 does not exist")}});
```

The TD tag (#td5) lies below the TD tag (#td2). When I try the same test on #table1 - a table that contains #td2 and #td5 - it does not disappear. Here is a simplification of the HTML:

```
<table id="table1"><tr>
<td id="td2"> ... </td>   <-- dynamically created select tag goes here
<td id="td4"><table id="table2"><tr><td> ... </td></tr></td> 
<td id="td5"> ... </td>
</tr></table>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What does "no longer works" mean? Is the alert not happening, or is it saying that table2 doesn't exist? There is no table2 in your HTML. Are you saying that things work if the id of the table containing #td2 and #td5 is `table1`, but not if the name is `table2`?

Comment: Before #td2 was modified, the alert gave the message "table2 exists". Afterwards, it gave the message "table2 does not exist".

Comment: table2 is after td4 on the HTML at the end of my question. I hope that helps.

Comment: I have set it up so that you can try it for yourselves.

Please try following:

http://emptyload.co.uk

click on td5 and you will get the alert"table2 exists"

refresh screen (F5) and select a car manufacturer and then click on td5 and you will get the alert "table2 does not exist"

Comment: No response from the emptyload.co.uk server. Maybe put it in a fiddle?

Comment: I am sorry about that Barmar. It is my PC. It will be running for next 12 hours - or I will move problem to proper server.

Comment: Still no response. Connecting to port 80 is timing out, maybe there's a firewall in the way?

Comment: Thanks for trying Barmar. 

I have put this example on http://www.bullionvault.com.au/
and it should be visible 24/24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After following the [link](http://www.bullionvault.com.au) in your comment above:

The `table` with id `table2` is inside the `td` with id `td4`. You have the `change1()` function bound to the change event of the `select` element. That function includes this line:

```
$("#td4").html("&nbsp;");
```

Which overwrites the original html with the non-breaking space. So the 2nd `alert` is correct. `table2 does not exist`.

Comment: Thank you Bryan. It was not at all obvious to me.